# using animate function on href click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a code which slides to a particular div on page load . I am trying to modify that code . I wish to slide it to particular div on click event of href.
[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/PPGPw/18/)

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv">DATA FOR SAMPLE 1</div>
<div id="what">SAMPLE DATA</div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"> on click<a/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where should it scroll? And the [selector context](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) is wrong, it should be `$('body', 'html')`, if that's what you are after...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to note here. If you give your `<a>` a link to a blank anchor, `href="#"`, it will automatically send you to the top of the page.

So in order to do this, you need to get rid of that.

```
<a>on click</a>
```

*It will still work if you don't remove the `href="#"`, but it will jump to the top of the page and back before it scrolls, which is unsightly.*

---

The other thing you need to do is bind the event to the `<a>`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     // Handler for .ready() called.
     $("a").click(function(){
         $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
        }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPGPw/20/)

Comment: I wish to use id with a , as I will not like this happen on every <a> , only this hint please, thanks

Comment: Then just use `<a id="something">` and do `$("#something").click...`

Answer (score 1):

TRY this. Here I am add a new id for your  tag ( recommended ) called `on_click_a` or you can use `$('a)` instead of `$('#on_click_a')`

```
<div id="mydiv">DATA FOR SAMPLE 1</div>
<div id="what">SAMPLE DATA</div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id='on_click_a'> on click<a/></li>
</ul>


$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $("#on_click_a").click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {    
     $('#clicky').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
         }, 'slow');
     });
 });
```

HTML

```
 <div id="mydiv">DATA FOR SAMPLE 1</div>
 <div id="what">SAMPLE DATA</div>
 <ul>
     <li><a id="clicky" href="#"> on click<a/></li>
 </ul>
```